# How to return true if there ISN'T a '.' before 'xyz' in the same string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a code where it returns True if within a given string xyz are there but there isn't a '.' in front of it example:'abc.xyz' should return False ,but 'abcxyz' returns True, this is what I made:

```
def xyz_there(str):
  for i in range(len(str)):
    if str[i:i+5]=='.xyz':
      return False
  return True
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean, but you could try with `str.endswith(".xyz")`. Anyway, calling a variable `str` is very bad, because it hides the in-built `str()` function.

Comment: Do you mean "immediately before" or just "before" - what would you expect from `'ab.cxyz'`?

Comment: I ran your code and it seems its doing what you are asking for

Comment: sorry for using 'str' as an argument , also it doesn't run well some instances is i put 'xy', 'x' an empty string or this ''abcxy'' the program runs this as true but it has to be false it must be 'xyz' as long as the . is not in front of 'xyz' specifically its true, I hope i've explained myself

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this is simply checking if 'xyz' is in the string but '.xyz' isn't. This if statement would look like this:

```
if 'xyz' in str and '.xyz' not in str:
    # code here
```

Comment: The question specifies that a '.' in front of 'xyz' should be an exception of returning `True`. This does not mean that the '.' symbol is not allowed in the string whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
isalpha()
```

For example:

```
'your string'.isalpha()
```

the above should return an output of `FALSE` if there are non-letters in your string.